# Fast sweeping / Fast marching Algorithm for non 0 boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms, boundary-value-problem

I have been scouting the internet for ways to numerically solve the eikonal equation:

$$|\nabla\phi(x)| = 1$$
$$\partial \phi = g(x)$$

Where $g(x)$ is known.

I know about both Fast Marching and Fast sweeping. However both of those seem to have been developed to solve 0 boundary conditions, at least when you read Hongkai's Zhao paper.

Is there a way to solve the problem when the boundary conditions are a known function (approximated as discrete point samples with known values on the grid upon which one runs the algorithm).

Comment: I would suggest you ask this on the [scicomp stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).